# R from grouped dataframe to Sankey diagram

Tags: r, dataframe, tree, grouping, sankey-diagram

I've been spending most of yesterdays time on the following problem and haven't found a solution yet to the following problem:

I have a dataframe with categorical data: say category1: has values A and B; Antother column category2 has values C, D, F, G; category3 has values H and so on...

I want to make a Sankey diagram showing how many (through the widths of the bands from node to node) from category1 A are in C, D, F, G. And this for all other combinations in the grouped dataframe as well.

It's basically a tree with the width of the branches showing how many counts are in the particular branch.

Is there a way on how to do this in a flexible way so that it works for most groupings in categorical DF's?

Answer (score 2):

You can try with the nice ggalluvial package:

```
library(ggalluvial)
library(ggplot2)

# some fake data
data <- data.frame(column1 = c('A','A','A','B','B','B')
                   ,column2 = c('C','D','E','C','D','E')
                   , column3 = c('F','G','H','I','J','K')
                               )

# add a costant as frequencies: if each "flow" count as 1, you can do this
data$freq <- 1

# here the plot
ggplot(data,
       aes(y = freq, axis1 = column1, axis2 = column2, axis3 = column3)) +
  geom_alluvium(aes(), width = 1/12) +
  geom_stratum(width = 1/12, fill = "black", color = "blue") +
  geom_label(stat = "stratum", label.strata = TRUE)  +
  scale_fill_brewer(type = "qual", palette = "Set1") +
  ggtitle("nice sankey")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to rearrange you're data into a node list and an edge list, you can take advantage of the D3 javascript library with the `networkD3` package.  Here's an example with dummy data (note that to use this library you need to have an id column which starts with 0.

```
library(tidyverse)

nodes <- tibble(id = c(0:9), label = c(1:10))

edges <- tibble(from = c(5:15, 0:4, 16:19), to = (0:19), weight = rnorm(20))

library(networkD3)

sankeyNetwork(Links = edges, 
              Nodes = nodes, 
              Source = "from", 
              Target = "to", 
              NodeID = "label", 
              Value = "weight")
```